# Allow users to type path in tkinter askopenfilename()

Tags: python, tkinter

**Environment:**

```
OS: Windows 7  
Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)  
Tkinter.TkVersion 8.5
```

I'm currently using **askopenfilename()** to allow users to specify/open files on Windows 7. This generates a dialog which allows users to navigate directories via the drop down menu highlighted here:

[image: askopenfilename() dialog]

Is it possible to modify the default behavior of the Tkinter askopenfilename dialog box in Windows to allow users to type a file path rather than using this drop down menu? E.g.,

[image]

I realize you can specify an initial path/directory with the "initialdir=" parameter, but I'd like to give users the convenience of typing/pasting a path as well.

Comment: maybe you can write folder name (to change folder) in place for file name. It works on Linux.

Comment: Furas, are you suggesting I use something like **askdirectory()** instead of **askopenfilename()**? That doesn't seem to achieve my goal. Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: No, I suggest that you can type directory name in `askopenfilename()` in place for filename and it will change directory.

Comment: On my system (details above), you cannot type in the highlighted area. You can only "choose" from a pull-down list. That's my problem!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on Ubuntu.  I can look at anything locally on the machine using only a pull down menu.  But, I can't type anything in to specify a network location.  I have to create a stupid dialogue box to ask the user to input a network location, then feed that into the initialdir parameter for it to work.  In windows, at least you can scroll through the left hand menu window to browse network locations.  In Ubuntu, there is only the current folder view and the current directory listed. :/

Answer (score 0):

using import os you can allow the user to type a path

```
import os
def Pathfinding(Select_path):
    my_path = Select_path
    user_path = os.chdir(my_path)
    return user_path
```

And this can be added to tkinter by calling the function using an Entry widget